# NetBeans - How to import another java file?

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

So in my source packages, I have one package called DiceRoller. Within that, I have two java files, one is MainApp.java and the second is TwoDice.java.

The MainApp is going to be the one I will be running. TwoDice.java will have the coding that will roll a pair of dice. I then want MainApp.java to display what numbers have been rolled.

Basically, if I declare

```
`int output = 12;`
```

in TwoDice.java, how would I be able to

```
system.out.println(output);
```

in MainApp.java and display 12 without having any errors?

Comment: Well, first you probably need to use a package, like the `package` keyword that goes at the top of each file.  If you're doing that, then we need to know what package you used for each file.

Comment: I have done that. Right after importing the scanner file. I have                        
 "import diceroller.TwoDice;" (without the quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both classes are in same package then no need to import it. In TwoDice.java you would have a method like this...

```
  public int getOutput() {
      return output;
   }
```

In you MainApp.java, you could then access it like this...

```
   private static void main(String[] args) {
        TwoDice dice = new TwoDice();
        System.out.println(dice.getOutput();
    }
```